# How is the "Google-Promote/Restore"-animation implemented?

Tags: javascript

I love the animation running when you promote (or later restore) a search result on google. This can be done by clicking the little arrows at the end of a result item.
The item is moved up or down with the rest of the page still visible. [Check it out](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ei=Y_zySuScOJqZjAf_6NSlDg&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CAYQBSgA&q=something&spell=1).

Did anyone work with the corresponding javascript or program a similar thing?

Comment: also, when you remove a result it disappears into a cloud that breaks open.

Comment: great too! Didn't see this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very quick right click after I click the remove button shows me the image below. Therefore, they must animate through the "frames" of the image by changing its position vertically.

For the promote/demote thing, it's probably something similar to this, but with the movement done automatically: http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

EDIT: Each search result is in its own list item. Judging by what changes I see in Firebug, the items that move are changed to absolute positioning, and animated up/down. When they are in place, the HTML code is switched around (so that, say, the third list item is now the first) and the positioning removed.

[image]